# How to change data array items asynchronously, adding and slicing

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to modify an array of items in my vuejs app after the app has loaded.

I have something like this:

```
var n = 100;
var myData = [];
function loadMovies(n){
  // async ajax requests
  // add items to myData with myData.push()
}
loadMovies(n)


var app = new Vue({
  router,
  data: {
     option_n_movies: n
    ,movies: myData
  },
  computed: {
    n_movies(){
      return this.movies.length;
    },
  }
  ,methods: {
    changeN(){
      if(this.option_n_movies > this.n_movies) loadMovies(this.option_n_movies);
      if(this.option_n_movies < this.n_movies) {
        myData = myData.slice(0, this.option_n_movies );
      }
    },
  }
}).$mount('#app');
```

(`option_n_movies` is linked with a `v-model="option_n_movies" v-on:change="changeN"` to an input and should allow to change the number of items in my array)

It almost works, but at some point I think that the link between `app.$data.movies` and `myData` is lost.
Meaning that I can add items to `myData` and they will reflect into `app.$data.movies`.

The problem is with `slice()` : When slicing `myData` it's not reflected in `app.$data.movies`. Then the link is lost because adding wont work anymore too.

What am I doing wrong?
Are there better ways to do this?

Comment: Use `Array.prototype.splice` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) leaves the original array untouched, end retruns a new array:

> The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from begin to end (end not included). The original array will not be modified.

```js
var myData = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var myData2 = myData.slice(2)
console.log(myData)
console.log(myData2)
```

So your code is essentially equal to:

```js
var myData = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
movies = myData
myData = myData.slice(2)

// myData is not the same array as movies
console.log(myData === movies)
```

What you want to do is to use [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove the elements from the array.

```js
var myData = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
movies = myData
myData.splice(0, 2)

// both arrays are still the same
console.log(myData===movies)

console.log(movies)
```